# How to block Iphone game using router setting?

Tags: iphone, block, router

Is there any way to block the iphone game using parental control in router? Hope you guys can help me out..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could connect the iphone to a computer and then using a proxy like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/), try to identify the specific URLs that potentially are accessed when playing the game. After you obtain that, it's easy to block access to that specific URLs from your router's admin interface.

However, this will work only if the game is an online one and needs to pull or push data from the internet. Otherwise, there's no way of blocking it from the router